# 'DATEFROMPARTS' is not a recognized built-in function name- SQL Server 2008 error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-function

```
Declare  @i int=1;
select FORMAT(DATEFROMPARTS(1900, @i, 1), 'MMM', 'en-US')
```

I'm getting an error while executing in SQL Server 2008.

> 'DATEFROMPARTS' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: That's a **new feature** in SQL Server **2012** and it's not available in older versions.

Comment: you will also find that FORMAT doesn't work there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the month name, use `datename()`:

```
select left(datename(month,
                     convert(date,
                             convert(varchar(255), 19000001 + @i * 100
                                    )
                            )
                     ), 3)
```

The explicit conversion to date is -- technically speaking -- unnecessary:

```
select left(datename(month, convert(varchar(255), 19000001 + 1 * 100)), 3)
```

Comment: This isn't equivalent to the original code. You would need a `LEFT(,3)`

Comment: No problem. Congratulations in advance for reaching 1 million rep!

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . Not just yet . . . as I write this 999,325.

Answer (score 4):

`DATEFROMPARTS` was introduced in SQL Server 2012. SQL Server 2008 (an unsupported SQL Server version), knows nothing about the function. If you need that functionality in SQL 2008, you'll need to create your implementation. Example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_DateFromParts (@year int, @month int, @day int)
RETURNS date
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN DATEADD(day, @day-1, DATEADD(month, @month-1, DATEADD(year, @year-1, CAST('0001-01-01' AS date))));
END;
GO
```

Similarly ,`FORMAT` was also introduced in SQL Server 2012. You'll need a SQLCLR function implication for that one.

Comment: CLR seems like overkill for mapping a month number to one of 12 possible strings

Comment: @MartinSmith, that is true for this specific use case. I was thinking of a replacement for all `FORMAT` functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the built in functions you are calling exist in SQL Server 2008

Personally I wouldn't bother constructing a date from the month number and then calling a function to get the abbreviated month string anyway.

You can use

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec',@i*3-2,3)
```